# Small multiple bar charts in one chart in PowerBI Dashboard

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a dashboard which has multiple visualizations(charts) out of which one is multiple small bar charts with 7 items and it is taking up the entire space. If I shrink the visual it is shrinking but giving me scroll bar and my business doesn't want a scroll option and want everything in one glance

Any way to shrink/compress the window or expand the Powerbi page or so? OR any way to shrink the small multiple bar charts visual to one real small and concise chart

Thanks,
Vyas

Comment: Can you add a screenshot here? There is an option of increasing the Page size and probably that's the option for you.

Answer (score 1):

On bar charts you can use the properties to help squeeze the most out of your screen space (see image below). However, if you find you are trying to squeeze too much on a screen, consider:

1. Reducing the amount of data to show, too much data is hard to consume
2. [Using drill through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough) and [drill down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-drill) (and training your audience how to use this)
3. [Using tool tip visuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-tooltips)
4. Separate reports for separate audiences (maybe sales and production need two different  views)
5. Using tables with conditional formatting to show bars.
6. Using matrices to have aggregations and drill downs.

[image]